# Query Regarding parameters settings of SVM

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, svm

For my experiment, i would like to build a SVM tree kernel model by tuning the weight of the contribution of trees and cost factor of the trees. So, how do I manipulate and find these parameters in the scikit-learn as I couldn't find any parameter named cost factor in the 1.4 Support Vector Machines scikit-learn documentation. Any suggestions or answers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: don't know much about svm models, but maybe it's the `gamma` paramater?

Comment: what do you mean by "trees"? There are no trees in SVM, unless you are working with graphs as input and with Tree Kernel (not available in scikit-learn).

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `C` parameter in scikit-learn's SVM implementation. This is the parameter usually called the *penalty term* or *cost factor* depending on the reference, and its value controls the extent to which the algorithm penalizes misclassification of training samples.